# How to log in on multiple sites with one log in?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, meteor, logging, oauth-2.0

I've tried to Google this for a while now, but haven't found anything yet. Mostly because I'm not even sure what type of resources and what in general I should be looking for.

This question might be too broad, so if there's no good way to answer this, I'd be glad to be pointed to corresponding resources from where I could read and learn more about this.

My scenario is following:

> I have two sites Site A and Site B.
>
> A user logs in on site A. Site A redirects the log in, so that the person is asked to log in on site B.
>
> If log in succeeds, the person is also logged in on site A and some information from site B is sent to site A. Otherwise user isn't logged in on any site.

Log in methods can be some custom or google sign in for example. I know from several sites that this kind of scenario is possible, but I have no idea of how this could be implemented.

These systems could physically be on different servers and there's no really a need for two way communication, though that would be great to learn too.

I know the basics of single site log in and how to do that and authorize access etc, but is there a way to authorize a user on some other site as well with that single authorization?

Technologies I've planned to use in this are Meteor, React and OAuth 2.0, but general or different solution is appreciated as well, if there's no way to implement this with those technologies.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing sounds quite a lot like a typical use-case for OAuth2.

Comment: So this is possible to achieve with OAuth2, even though the actual log in on Site B was made with for example using Google logging? I've been reading OAuth2 a lot, but somehow gave up as I thought that I can't share the log in info to another site with it. I guess I'm thinking this is more complex than it actually is...

Comment: Agree this sounds like SSO using OAuth2. If both sites share a domain then you might be able to simplify that.